# Ruby find method callers class

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I have classes `A` and `B`, each with methods `a` and `b` respectively, like below.

```
class A
  def a
    #I want to get the object which calls this method
    #caller = B
  end
end

class B
  def initialize
    @to_call = A.new
  end
  def b
    @to_call.a
  end
end

B.new.b
```

How can I return `B` that calls `a` so that I can use methods of `B` inside `A`?

I have a class `Board`, which `Game` classes use to play. The board class has a method `interact` that gets user input either with `gets.chomp` or `STDIN.getc` to simulate guessing games or games which use arrow keys. The game class calls the interact method to begin playing the game, and sends it a block that handles the way the game is played. Each game has its own set of rules, therefore each game class has a method that displays its rule book to the user. Within `interact`, when the user enters `"-rules"`, I want the board class to return the class that called its `interact` method and store it in a variable `caller`. With the `caller` variable defined, I want to use `caller.rule_book` to display the rules of the game class that called the board's `interact` method.

Comment: You seem to be using the word "object" in the sense of "class". I fixed the clear cases, but left the unclear cases. Can you fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know a way you you could do it, besides using the source's location (`caller_locations`), but I'd advise not to follow this path. Too much indirection often leads to code extremely hard to debug. It's much simpler and readable to simply pass the context (in this case, `self`, or the properties needed for the computation) as an argument:

```
class A
  def initialize(context)
    @context = context
  end

  def a
    # Do something with @context
  end
end

class B
  def initialize
    @to_call = A.new(self)
  end

  def b
    @to_call.a
  end
end

B.new.b
```